# CSS hover for blackberry but not iphone?

Tags: iphone, css, blackberry, mousehover

Im mobile optimizing a site and ive made a flyout menu. Ive disabled changing the colour of the menu button on :hover. I did this as the iPhone considers the last clicked to keep the hover pseudo-class.

However now im testing on blackberry and they have an desktop style cursor and so would benefit from the element changing colour on mouseover.

Is it possible to disable the hover color for iPhones but not for blackberrys? More generally, is there a way to have a hover color only for non-touch screen devices like blackberrys, as only they can really mouseover. 
Thanks

Comment: Not without explicit device detection, I don't think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers the first part of your question.
Try using Modernizr and then adding an appleOS test.

```
Modernizr.addTest('ipad', function () {
  return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
});

Modernizr.addTest('iphone', function () {
  return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
});

Modernizr.addTest('ipod', function () {
  return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i);
});

Modernizr.addTest('appleios', function () {
  return (Modernizr.ipad || Modernizr.ipod || Modernizr.iphone);
});
```

From there, you could add a class to the body if it's iOS and apply the hover classes for only non-iOS devices.

Ideally, you could just use the "notouch" body class that Modernizr adds to browser that don't support touch, but in my experience it does not add this class to Blackberry browsers, even if the device doesn't support touch. Let me know if you find differently!

Comment: I support the use of Modernizr, but this approach is a bit much. There's a simple Modernizr.touch object that is more to the point of what the asker wants. So, if you're detecting via javascript, you can do this: if(!Modernizr.touch) { // enter no-touch hovers here }. If you're doing it via CSS, you can use Modernizr's classnames, and do something like .no-touch .className:hover { // enter styles here }.

Comment: I definitely agree that this approach is a bit much, but you'll see that I mentioned the Modernizr.touch and .no-touch classnames, and I've found that Modernizr thinks that Blackberry browsers (even those which don't support touch) DO support touch. Like I said, though, if someone has found differently, then good!